# I want my Tabs to appear in every activity but it only appears in the activity where the tabs are assigned

Tags: android, android-activity, android-tabhost

When in Home tab, there is a List View of menus that you can click. And if you click one, it will go to a new activity but the tab is gone.I want tab to appear in this new activity and other activities as well.

Here is my Main activity(onCreate)

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    hostTab = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
    hostTab.setup(this.getLocalActivityManager());

    //setting tabs(images)
    mIntent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
    specTab = hostTab.newTabSpec("home").setIndicator(" ",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.home_tab)).setContent(mIntent);
    hostTab.addTab(specTab);
    hostTab.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.home_tab);
    //hostTab.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(150,50));

    mIntent = new Intent(this, ContactUsActivity.class);
    specTab = hostTab.newTabSpec("contactUs").setIndicator(" ",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.contact_us_tab)).setContent(mIntent);
    hostTab.addTab(specTab);
    hostTab.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.contact_us_tab);

    mIntent = new Intent(this, TravelDetailsActivity.class);
    specTab = hostTab.newTabSpec("travelDetails").setIndicator(" ",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.travel_details_tab)).setContent(mIntent);
    hostTab.addTab(specTab);
    hostTab.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.travel_details_tab);

    mIntent = new Intent(this, PortGuide.class);
    specTab = hostTab.newTabSpec("portGuide").setIndicator(" ",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.port_guide_tab)).setContent(mIntent);
    hostTab.addTab(specTab);
    hostTab.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.port_guide_tab);

    mIntent = new Intent(this, MoreMenu.class);
    specTab = hostTab.newTabSpec("more").setIndicator(" ",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.more_tab)).setContent(mIntent);
    hostTab.addTab(specTab);
    hostTab.getTabWidget().getChildAt(4).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.more_tab);

}
```

Here is my main activity xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:id="@+id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"  >
    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">
       <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp" 
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </FrameLayout>
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:gravity="bottom">
        </TabWidget>
     </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Please feel free to comment what I'm missing to post for you to further understand my problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a `FragmentActivity` to host multiple `Fragments` as children. You will be able to keep the tabs with a `FragmentTabHost`.

See:
[FragmentTabHost Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html)
[TabHost Tutorial](http://blog.ace-art.fr/2010/10/13/tutoriel-android-partie-11-les-tabhost/)
[Creating a Tab Layout with FragmentTabHost and Fragments](http://maxalley.wordpress.com/2013/05/18/android-creating-a-tab-layout-with-fragmenttabhost-and-fragments/)

Hope will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks.I will keep you posted if I can make it work.:)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a base activity and write code related to tabs in it.

Extend all activities with that activity and in xml layouts of all activities include part relates to tabs.

Create a BaseActivity have have following function init:

```
public class BaseActivity extende Activity{

    public void init(){

     hostTab = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
        hostTab.setup(this.getLocalActivityManager());

        //setting tabs(images)
        mIntent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
        specTab = hostTab.newTabSpec("home").setIndicator(" ",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.home_tab)).setContent(mIntent);
        hostTab.addTab(specTab);
        hostTab.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.home_tab);
        //hostTab.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(150,50));

        mIntent = new Intent(this, ContactUsActivity.class);
        specTab = hostTab.newTabSpec("contactUs").setIndicator(" ",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.contact_us_tab)).setContent(mIntent);
        hostTab.addTab(specTab);
        hostTab.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.contact_us_tab);

        mIntent = new Intent(this, TravelDetailsActivity.class);
        specTab = hostTab.newTabSpec("travelDetails").setIndicator(" ",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.travel_details_tab)).setContent(mIntent);
        hostTab.addTab(specTab);
        hostTab.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.travel_details_tab);

        mIntent = new Intent(this, PortGuide.class);
        specTab = hostTab.newTabSpec("portGuide").setIndicator(" ",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.port_guide_tab)).setContent(mIntent);
        hostTab.addTab(specTab);
        hostTab.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.port_guide_tab);

        mIntent = new Intent(this, MoreMenu.class);
        specTab = hostTab.newTabSpec("more").setIndicator(" ",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.more_tab)).setContent(mIntent);
        hostTab.addTab(specTab);
        hostTab.getTabWidget().getChildAt(4).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.more_tab);

    }
}
```

And Other activities will extend this one

```
public class PortGuide extends BaseActivity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.<PortGuide layout>);
init();
}

}
```

Just make sure you have this:

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:id="@+id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"  >
```

in  all layouts

Comment: Can you give me an example? I'm new to android programming. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Sir, will i edit my entire post above with the code you answered?

Comment: I m not able to see any changes in your post. And also I forgot to extend PortGuide with BaseActivity so do that as well.

Comment: It produces errors in Log Cat saying unable to start Activity(NullpointerException) :(

Comment: Post your new code and your logcat may help us to resolve your issue ;)

Comment: The solution posted by Sir vipul goes like this. I can see the tabs in the Notifications Activity but when I press the Tab for other Activity(e.g Home,Contact Us etc.) the Activity for the Notifications retains.Please help.:(

Comment: you should edit your post and put the code you are trying for Home and Contact Us activity + xml layouts.